# Is there a difference between a so called "Variable" and a so called "Pointer"?

Tags: objective-c

I always wonder if it's correct to say that something like THIS is a "pointer", rather than a "variable":

```
NSString *fooStr = ...;
```

Would you call "fooStr" a "pointer" rather than a "variable"? Or is it okay to say both here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer:

A pointer is a variable that contains the location of data memory, whereas a variable contains the data itself.

So you CAN call a pointer a variable, but calling it a pointer is more specific.

Comment: True.  And variable pointer would be something wholly different :)

Answer (score 2):

A pointer's data type is always an address.  A variable's data type is what you set it to.